# Kubernetes autoscaling and logs of created / deleted pods

Tags: kubernetes, logging, google-kubernetes-engine

I am implementing a Kubernetes based solution where I am autoscaling a deployment based on a dynamic metric. I am running this deployment with autoscaling capabilities against a workload for 15 minutes. During this time, pods of this deployment are created and deleted dynamically as a result of the deployment autoscaling decisions.

I am interested in saving (for later inspection) of the logs of  each of the dynamically created (and potentially deleted) pods  occuring in the course of the autoscaling experiment.

If the deployment has a label like **app=myapp** ,  can I run the below command to store all the logs of my deployment?

```
kubectl logs -l app=myapp  > myfile.txt
```

Any other more reliable suggestion (without the overhead of manual central logging solution) ?  I am runnig on goole kubernetes engine GKE,  Does the GKE keep the logs of deleted pods?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by default GKE sends logs for *all* pods to Stackdriver and you can view/query them there.